# Confusing file permissions issues when uploading wordpress plugins

Tags: php, apache, ftp, wordpress

I'm on my own Ubuntu box on AWS. I have two users: medsyd (the owner of my wordpress site) and www-data (which apache runs as). For now, to try get things working, I've added both to each other's groups - so www-data belongs to the medsyd group, and medsyd belongs to the www-data group.

I'm trying to make it so that wordpress can upload/install plugins without asking for FTP access. I can upload images/media just fine - but plugins seem to be behaving really weirdly and not following what I would expect given the file permissions.

Here's what I've tried:

1. medsyd:medsyd as the owner of the site directory and all it's contents; 775 directories, 664 files. Wordpress asks for FTP. Why? (the www-data user should be able to write/read the correct files since it belongs to the medsyd group)
2. medsyd:www-data as the owner of the site directory and all it's contents; 775 directories, 664 files. Wordpress asks for FTP. Why? (the www-data user should be able to write to read/write the correct files, since the files all belong to the www-data group)
3. www-data:www-data as the owner of the site directory and all it's contents; 775 directories, 664 files. Wordpress does NOT ask for FTP. YAY. But www-data shouldn't own all my files.
4. www-data:www-data as the owner of the wp-content directory (and all it's contents) ONLY (everything else outside wp-content owned by medsyd:medsyd); 775 directories, 664 files. Wordpress ASKS for FTP. (Why does this differ from the example just above, which worked, where www-data owns everything outside the wp-content directory aswell?)

What logic does wordpress use to decide whether or not to ask for FTP when installing plugins? I can't seem to think of any that would reconcile with the 4 examples above.

Edit: I understand there are other ways around this - eg changing the user apache runs as, storing FTP credentials in wp-config etc, but regardless, I really what to understand why the permissions I'm using above aren't behaving as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to run apache as "medsyd" user. Other ways requires more complicated server configuration.

Open file /etc/apache2/envvars and change following lines:

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=medsyd
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=medsyd
```

Then restart apache. service apache2 restart

## update

If you have multiple sites and would like to separate them, I suggest you read about mpm_itk.

I will try to explain why you hae troubles with 775 privileges. The GROUP privilege affects only users with the same PRIMARY group. Other groups does not matter.

For example, you have "www" directory, owned by medsyd:medsyd. Permissions are 775. Apache will not be able to write there, because it primary group is www-data. You should change Apache UID/GID to www-data:medsyd, I mean change it PRIMARY group.

But anyway, if you would like to complitely separate several sites, this way is not for you, because one compromised site can access all others. mpm_itk would be better in such case.

Comment: I know there's some other solutions. I've actually got multiple sites running under different users, so that wouldn't work verbatim. I do know that there's ways to get your solution working for multiple users/sites, too. But regardless, I'd really like to understand why the file permissions above aren't working.

Comment: my comment was too long, please read the "update" in the answer